# Selenium java automation test: Start docker-compose inside Gitlab CI and run gradle test occurs exception

Tags: docker, selenium, gradle, continuous-integration, gitlab

I am writing gitlab-ci.yml to enable check result e2e test on Gitlab:
**Step 1**: Run “docker-compose up -d” 
**Step 2**: Run “gradle test –info” 
The following current gitlab-ci.yml file (02 job with 02 image):

```
build:
  stage: build
  image: docker/compose:latest
  services:
    - name: docker:dind
    #- name: gradle:5.4.1
  script:
    - docker-compose version 
    - docker-compose up -d
    #- gradle test --info
    #- docker compose down
test:
  image: gradle:alpine
  #stage: test
  script:
  - gradle -v
  - gradle test --info
```

The following docker-compose.yaml file:

```
services:
  selenium-hub:
    image: selenium/hub:3.141.59-20200409
    container_name: selenium-hub
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome-debug:3.141.59-20200409
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - HUB_HOST=selenium-hub
      - HUB_PORT=4444
    ports:
      - "5900:5900"
```

When i run pipeline and throws exception:

> Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver Caused
>   by:java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to
>   localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:4444
>   I run successfully in locally. But on Gitlab runner, seems selenium/hub container not started when run gradle test.
>   Please tell me how to use configuration run 1 job with multi image.
>   Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add network to the docker-compose or use bridge.

Example:

```
services:
  selenium-hub:
    image: selenium/hub:3.141.59-20200409
    container_name: selenium-hub
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
    networks:
      - selenium
  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome-debug:3.141.59-20200409
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - HUB_HOST=selenium-hub
      - HUB_PORT=4444
    ports:
      - "5900:5900"
    networks:
      - selenium
networks:
    selenium:
        name: selenium-network
        driver: bridge
```

Comment: I try to run pipeline as your suggestion but got same exception. I am thinking using 1 image that can run docker-compose and gradle. It possible ?

Comment: you can do it with 1 or (n) images, paste the error

Comment: Thanks you for your support.
Gitlab runner throws exception is samely before using network and bridge
 `
 Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:573)
   
Caused by:
 java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:4444
  at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:247)
Caused by:
 java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
`

Comment: @Infern0 are you famillier with this issue https://gitlab.com/letsknow101/springboot-demo-maven/-/issues/1